# Magento 2: How to remove billing section from checkout page

Tags: onepage-checkout

How to remove billing section from checkout page on Magnto2.4.5
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create di.xml file

```
    <?xml version = "1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
            <plugin name="remove_checkout_billing_address_fields"
type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Checkout\BillingRemoveAddress" sortOrder="1"/>
        </type>
    </config>
```

Create BillingRemoveAddress.php

```
<?php
 
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Checkout;
 
use Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor;
 
class BillingRemoveAddress
{
    public function afterProcess(
        LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array $result
    )
    {
        $this->result = $result;
        $billingConfiguration = &$this->result['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']
        ['children']['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'];
 
        if (isset($billingConfiguration)) {
            foreach ($billingConfiguration as $key => &$billingForm) {
                if (!strpos($key, '-form')) {
                    continue;
                }
                if ($billingForm['children']['form-fields']['children']['remove_field']) {
                    unset($billingForm['children']['form-fields']['children']['city']);
                }
 
            }
        }
        return $this->result;
    }
}
```

and check it.